# How to call the base interface implementation when derived classes re-implement the interface?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

So, for one reason or another, I'm testing the limits of C# and the .NET VM. I came across a bit of perplexing behavior.

Take these classes and interfaces:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Test();
    void Test2();
}
public abstract class Base : ITest
{
    void ITest.Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base");
    }
    public void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base2");
    }
    public void Test3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base3");
    }
}
public class Impl : Base, ITest
{
    void ITest.Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("impl");
    }
    void ITest.Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("impl2");
    }
    public void Test3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("impl3");
    }
}
```

And then use them like so:

```
        var i = new Impl();
        var b = (Base)i;
        var itest1 = (ITest)i;
        var itest2 = (ITest)b;
        itest1.Test();
        itest2.Test();
        itest1.Test2();
        itest2.Test2();
        i.Test2();
        b.Test2();
        i.Test3(); //for reference, a standard non-virtual method outside of an interface
        b.Test3();
```

I expected for the output to look something like so:

```
impl
base
impl2
base2
impl2
base2
impl3
base3
```

But of course, things can't be that simple. So, the actual output is this:

```
impl
impl
impl2
impl2
base2
base2
impl3
base3
```

Beyond this crazy weird behavior, is it possible to access the Base.Test() implementation?

Comment: Doing what it should as far as I can see. Casting is not converting.

Comment: Precisely, casting is not converting. Besides, I'd suggest renaming the question slightly: **How to call the base interface explicit implementation when derived classes explicit re-implement the interface?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check why you find the results you get weird. To me it looks like you got exactly what you implemented.

There is no way to get `Base.Test` because there is no `Base.Test`. You need to access this through the interface explicitly and then it's no longer `Base`, but `Impl`, because the underlying real object is not of type `Base`.

Comment: But if you add a `Test3` method to both Base and Impl, but not to the interface, then you see the base3, impl3 behavior that I'm expecting

Comment: It seems like it treats interface implementations as always being virtual, but they are not marked virtual. I would expect this behavior if everything was virtualk

Comment: The key here is that you re-implemented the interface in Impl. So it will use its native implementation rather than the implementation inherited from Base.

Comment: @NickZimmerman but how? It's cast to a Base, so why would it not use Base's implementation?

Comment: @Earlz: because you are accessing it through `ITest` at all times!!! Intermediary casts ain't gonna help you!!!

Comment: Because it's not accessed through the base variable. And it is not of type base. So why would it call the base's code.

Comment: ahhh.. I see what you mean

Comment: Even though you cast to Base, that interface implementation will be ignored because you explicitly re-implemented the interface in the child. Whatever the newest implementation of the interface in the inheritance chain is the one that will be used. You are effectively overriding the ancestor's implementation. So when you cast to ITest is takes the latest version.

Comment: The only thing I still don't understand then is when I remove the explicit interface implementation from Test, then it will access the base implementation after casting to ITest. I would expect casting to ITest to use the implementation highest up the inheritance chain regardless of explicit or implicit implementations. (that is, make it just `void Test` in Impl, but leaving Base as is)

Comment: Notice that when you don't cast to ITest, you get the Base implementation because it goes through the inheritance chain, taking the inherited version.

Comment: Interfaces aren't inherited. They are implemented, so whenever you make a new implementation, it becomes the current implementation. So if you cast to that interface (ITest, in this case), you get the latest implementation.

Comment: ahh, when converting from explicit to implicit interface, I forgot the `public`. After adding that back in, I do see the expected "latest interface" behavior. It's weird though because if I leave the interface only partially implemented in Impl, then I get calls from both Impl and Base, which is weird that it mixes those instead of throwing a compiler error

Comment: What you are seeing is expected behavior. You can partially re-implement an interface that is already implemented in an ancestor without the compiler complaining because it sees that the whole interface is implemented somewhere in the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 0):

`Base` is explicitly implementing `ITest.Test()`. It's an implementation, but it's a **"private"** implementation, only accessible through the `ITest` interface.

On top of that, `Impl` is **re-implementing** `ITest.Test()`, so when you try your `itest2.Test()` you are going to point to this later **re-implementation**.

The 2 key points here are:

1. There is no public `Base.Test()`.
2. You killed all your possibilities of accessing the `ITest.Test()` implementation on `Base` by **re-implementing** it on `Impl`.

### Re-implementation, re-implementation, re-implementation.

May I suggest renaming the question slightly: **How to call the base interface explicit implementation when derived classes explicit re-implement the interface?** Because that's what you are asking...